# Group pandas df according to set

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering if there's a faster way to grouping according to a set. Here's the operation:

```
import pandas as pd
col1 = 'ABCDE'
col2 = range(5,10)
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(col1,col2), columns=('x','y'))

row_groups = {'foo':set('ABC'), 'bar':set('DE')}
```

I want to change the data frame from its current form:

```
    x    y                     y
0   A    5         group_name
1   B    6         foo         18
2   C    7  ==>    bar         17 
3   D    8
4   E    9
```

The way I did it was to create a second data frame representing the groups, merge the two data frames, group by the row group names, and sum,

```
row_groups_df = pd.DataFrame(zip('ABCDE',['foo']*3 + ['bar']*2), 
                             columns=('x','group_name'))
merged_df = pd.merge(df, row_groups_df)
output_df = merged_df.groupby(['group_name']).sum()
```

Which yields the desired output:

```
            y
group_name  
bar        17
foo        18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way, but you can do this:

```
df.groupby('x', axis = 0).sum()\
  .groupby(lambda x: (k for k,v in row_groups.iteritems() if x in v).next()).sum()
```

or replace `df.groupby('x', axis = 0).sum()` with `df.set_index('x')`:

```
df.set_index('x').\
   groupby(lambda x: (k for k,v in row_groups.iteritems() if x in v).next()).sum()
```

The output is as requested:

```
      y
bar  17
foo  18
```